# Replacing quantified capturing groups

Tags: regex

I have a string which looks like:

```
Alabama,AL,Montgomery,Birmingham,4833722.0,1450116.6,,52420 (135767),,50645 (131170)
```

Now I'm interested in producing this output:

```
Alabama,AL,Montgomery,Birmingham,4833722.0,1450116.6,52420,135767,50645,131170
```

Now the following regex captures: `,,52420 (135767),,50645 (131170)`:

```
(,,(\d+) \((\d+)\)){2}
```

However (I **do** know that) the capturing groups `\2` and `\3` will capture only the last pair.
Of course I could have written this regex like this: `(,,(\d+) \((\d+)\))(,,(\d+) \((\d+)\))` but I was wondering if there is any way to prevent duplicating the regex pattern many times? What if instead of 2 repetitions it was some general integer `k`? Is there a way to access the capture groups independently? I mean it would be great if I could do something like this: `,\1,\2,\3,\4`

Answer (score 1):

Well, `{k}` would generally be replaced with either the `*` or `+` repetition operator; repeating the group construct but if you have capture groups in conjuction with the repeated group, only the last iteration will be captured and it wouldn't be possible to access individual groups.

```
,,(\d+) \((\d+)\)(?:,,(\d+) \((\d+)\))*
```

You can see how the engine works with the repeated group — [live demo](https://regex101.com/r/nX4mJ9/1).

> Is there a way to access the capture groups independently?
>
> I mean it would be great if I could do something like this: `,\1,\2,\3,\4`

But, to use individual groups for the above context you could simply do:

```
,,(\d+) \((\d+)\),,(\d+) \((\d+)\)
```

[**Live Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/pJ4sG5/2)

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to replace everything at once.  Just capture one number at a time (`(\d+(\.\d+)?)`), along with whatever non-number characters follow it (`\W+`), and replace the latter with a single comma.  That might leave you with a trailing comma, but you can strip it off separately.  Here's how it might look in Java:

```
s = s.replaceAll("(\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)\\W+", "$1,").replaceAll(",$", "");
```

Here's an online demo of the the first part: [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/pJ4sG5/3)